# Interfacing with the Windows API via Clozure CL

Tags: common-lisp, ffi, ccl

I want to call a Windows API function from Clozure CL via its Foreign Function Interface, but I am having some issues because the documentation I have been able to find is rather scarce.

As a sufficiently rich example, I am trying to call [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx).
Its signature is

```
HRESULT SHGetKnownFolderPath(const GUID &rfid, DWORD dwFlags,
                             HANDLE hToken, PWSTR *ppszPath   );
```

#### Getting the entry point

I can use the following to get the entry point of the function:

```
(open-shared-library "shell32.dll")
> #<SHLIB SHELL32.dll #x1234>
(external "SHGetKnownFolderPath")
> #<EXTERNAL-ENTRY-POINT "SHGetKnownFolderPath" (#x12345) SHELL32.dll #x123456>
```

#### Getting/setting the correct method signature

Here's what I think the general steps are for calling it, but I am unsure about the how of each:

- Retrieve the signature that CCL has generated for this function so I can know how to call it.
- Provide a different function signature for it using `external-call`.
- Define an FFI structure or class to hold the `GUID` (first argument) via `def-foreign-type` or related construct.
- After the call, use `CoTaskMemFree` to free the memory pointed to by `*ppszPath`.

#### A guess at the form of the eventual code

My guess for the general form the final code would take is

```
(defun get-known-folder (guid)
   (let ((ffi-guid (allocate-ffi-memory-from-guid guid))
         (ffi-path ffi-version-of-nil)
         (path nil))
      (external-call "SHGetKnownFolderPath" ...) ;; Pass ffi-guid and ffi-path by reference.
      (setf path (convert-cstring-to-string ffi-path))
      (external-call "CoTaskMemFree" ...) ;; Free ffi-path.
      path))
```

where there are still the various unknown functions and function calls to convert between C/FFI and Lisp.

#### Addendum

I'm quite familiar with the Windows API and have done Win32 API calls from other languages. I also managed to get this working in CLisp, up to a point, as I ran into the problem of poor Unicode support of CLisp in Windows (I ended up with only the first character of the path, because CLisp reads the UTF-16 string as ASCII).

The point I am stuck on is what functionality there is in CCL to make this work.
Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend to use the Clozure CL mailing list for such a very specific question. There it's most likely to get some answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CFFI?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm looking through the CFFI code; I can probably use it directly, but I'm first going to try and distil what I need from it to answer this question.